# Win 10 bash shell and highlighting of the directories in console

Tags: bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I implemented bash shell into my windows 10 as "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows".

And now I just want to remove the highlight from folders in console.

Additionally I use bashIt library to change design of my console but I don't know how to change that hightlight :(

Comment: Just letting you know that the link to the image no longer works.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I find an answer and if somebody need it there is solution.

You need to add this :

```
export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ow=1;34:';
```

into your .bashrc file

More information here :
http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors

or here :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/466198/how-do-i-change-the-color-for-directories-with-ls-in-the-console

Comment: Why folders are highlighted? it only seems like folders having full permission (or permission vulnerability are highlighted

Comment: I'm curious why they're different as well. If I `mkdir` on a windows filesystem, the folder is highlighted by bash, yet `file` and `ls -l` don't show any differences, and somehow not all directories on the windows fs are highlighted.